# Why doesn't MS-DOS initialize the DS and ES registers?

Tags: assembly, dos, intel, masm, x86-16

Why does the initialization of the `DS` and `ES` registers has to be done manually by the programmer?

For example:

```
MOV AX, DTSEG
MOV DS, AX
```

On the other hand, the `CS` and `SS` registers are initialized by the operating system (in `MS-DOS`). Why is this so?

Comment: Wow. Next, I want to see someone ask a question about punch cards :-)

Comment: Yeah.I had a lot of them,solved few weeks ago !

Comment: @Dave, it's a perfectly valid question for Windows as well

Comment: Which version of MS-DOS? On which hardware?

Comment: in fact all MS-DOS versions ,even some of the windows ( till windows 1.3 )

Comment: @John: Did you just ask what hardware MS-DOS runs on?

Comment: dos runs on a wide variety of x86 processors, ES and DS usage is affected by which family you are using.  it is a valid question.

Comment: I once had an MS-DOS device driver that failed only on Leading Edge computers - they initialized the interrupt vectors differently.

Comment: Also, remember that MS-DOS was an OS that could be modified by the OEM to an extent. This question may have different answers depending on the hardware.

Answer (score 9):

Because `CS` and `SS` registers are essential for program execution in contrast to `DS` and `ES` registers which point to user-defined data segments. By default no data is present in the executing program this nothing to initialize the `DS` and `ES` with. As a program writer you can specify where your data is by setting the data segments registers.

**Edit**: as was correctly noted by @FrankKotler, in `.com` file (the entire program size doesn't exceed single segment), `DS` and `ES` are initialized and equal to `CS`. For other execution models, `DS` and `ES` are initialized by pointer to `PSP` (which isn't the pointer to real user data).

Comment: Strictly speaking, ds and es ARE initialized - to point to the PSP, not your data segment (which dos doesn't know - you could have more than one, or have data in your code segment). In a .com file, everything's in the same (PSP) segment, so ds and es are initialized correctly.

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer to your question (which i believe master V.Aghazarian has asked you in college) is not because CS ans SS are essential for program execution.

The problem in MS-DOS was with [Program Segment Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix)

From wikipedia:

> The segment address of the PSP is passed in the DS register when the program is executed. It can also be determined later by using Int 21h function 51h or Int 21h function 62h. Either function will return the PSP address in register BX.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix)