# x86 segmentation, DOS, MZ file format, and disassembling

Tags: dos, disassembly, 16-bit, memory-segmentation

I'm disassembling "Test Drive III". It's a 1990 DOS game. The *.EXE has MZ format.
I've never dealt with segmentation or DOS, so I would be grateful if you answered some of my questions.

1) The game's [system requirements](http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=15497&tab=sysreqs) mention 286 CPU, which has protected mode. As far as I know, DOS was 90% real mode software, yet some applications could enter protected mode. Can I be sure that the app uses the CPU in real mode only? IOW, is it guaranteed that the segment registers contain actual offset of the segment instead of an index to segment descriptor?

2) Said system requirements mention 1 MB of RAM. How is this amount of RAM even meant to be accessed if the uppermost 384 KB of the address space are reserved for stuff like MMIO and ROM? I've heard about UMBs (using holes in UMA to access RAM) and about HMA, but it still doesn't allow to access the whole 1 MB of physical RAM. So, was precious RAM just wasted because its physical address happened to be reserved for UMA? Or maybe the game uses some crutches like LIM EMS or XMS?

3) Is CS incremented automatically when the code crosses segment boundaries? Say, the IP reaches 0xFFFF, and what then? Does CS switch to the next segment before next instruction is executed? Same goes for SS. What happens when SP goes all the way down to 0x0000?

4) The MZ header of the executable looks like this:

```
signature 23117 "0x5a4d" 
bytes_in_last_block 117 
blocks_in_file 270 
num_relocs 0 
header_paragraphs 32 
min_extra_paragraphs 3349 
max_extra_paragraphs 65535 
ss 11422 
sp 128 
checksum 0 
ip 16 
cs 8385 
reloc_table_offset 30 
overlay_number 0
```

Why does it have no relocation information? How is it even meant to run without address fixups? Or is it built as completely position-independent code consisting from program-counter-relative instructions? The game comes with a cheat utility which is also an MZ executable. Despite being much smaller (8448 bytes - so small that it fits into a single segment), it still has relocation information:

```
offset 1 
segment 0 

offset 222 
segment 0 

offset 272 
segment 0
```

This allows IDA to properly disassemble the cheat's code. But the game EXE has nothing, even though it clearly has lots of far pointers.

5) Is there even such thing as 'sections' in DOS? I mean, data section, code (text) section etc? The MZ header points to the stack section, but it has no information about data section. Is data and code completely mixed in DOS programs?

6) Why even having a stack section in EXE file at all? It has nothing but zeroes. Why wasting disk space instead of just saying, "start stack from here"? Like it is done with BSS section?

7) MZ header contains information about initial values of SS and CS. What about DS? What's its initial value?

8) What does an MZ executable have after the exe data? The cheat utility has whole 3507 bytes in the end of the executable file which look like

```
__exitclean.__exit.__restorezero._abort.DGROUP@.__MMODEL._main._access.
_atexit._close._exit._fclose._fflush._flushall._fopen._freopen._fdopen
._fseek._ftell._printf.__fputc._fputc._fputchar.__FPUTN.__setupio._setvbuf
._tell.__MKNAME._tmpnam._write.__xfclose.__xfflush.___brk.___sbrk._brk._sbrk
.__chmod.__close._ioctl.__IOERROR._isatty._lseek.__LONGTOA._itoa._ultoa.
_ltoa._memcpy._open.__open._strcat._unlink.__VPRINTER.__write._free._malloc
._realloc.__REALCVT.DATASEG@.__Int0Vector.__Int4Vector.__Int5Vector.
__Int6Vector.__C0argc.__C0argv.__C0environ.__envLng.__envseg.__envSize
```

Is this some kind of debugging symbol information?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The game's executable may be compressed or otherwise protected from reverse-engineering. They could have used a position-independent wrapper that performs the fixups by itself, using a table that's not in the .EXE header but separate from it. I remember playing that game *a lot*, it wasn't unexpected for games to have various levels of reverse-engineering protection.

Comment: @KubaOber thank you for your answer. The game's EXE does not look compressed in any way. It just contains plain x86 opcodes. As for the custom wrapper, I couldn't find anything like this in the game's code.

Comment: Well, does the machine code look position independent all across the executable? You've just answered #4.

Comment: @KubaOber no, it has lots of instructions like `call far ptr 18DCh:78Ch`

Comment: Then you know that there is a wrapper somewhere that does address fixups or forcibly relocates the game to a constant address. If the game doesn't use DOS to access on-disk files, it can remove DOS completely and take over, gaining lots of memory in the process. I don't recall whether you could exit from the game back to the command prompt. Some games where "play until you reboot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re. 1. No, you can't be sure until you prove otherwise to yourself. One [giveaway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Entering_and_exiting_protected_mode) would be the presence of `MOV CR0, ...` in the code.

Re. 2. While marketing materials aren't to be confused with an engineering specification, there's a technical reason for this. A 286 CPU could address more than 1M of physical address space. The RAM was only "wasted" in real mode, and only if an EMM (or EMS) driver wasn't used. On 286 systems, the RAM past 640kb was usually "pushed up" to start at the 1088kb mark. The ISA and on-board peripherals' memory address space was mapped 1:1 into the 640-1024kb window. To use the RAM from the real mode needed an EMM or EMS driver. From protected mode, it was simply "there" as soon as you set up the segment descriptor correctly.

If the game actually needed the extra 384kb of RAM over the 640kb available in the real mode, it's a strong indication that it either switched to protected mode or required the services or an EMM or EMS driver.

Re. 3. I wish I remembered that. On reflection, I wish not :) Someone else please edit or answer separately. Hah, I did know it at some point in time :)

Re. 4. You say "[the code] has lots of instructions like call far ptr 18DCh:78Ch". This implies one of three things:

- Protected mode is used and the segment part of the address is a [selector into the segment descriptor table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Segment_addressing).
- There is code there that relocates those instructions without DOS having to do it.
- There is code there that forcibly relocates the game to a constant position in the address space. If the game doesn't use DOS to access on-disk files, it can remove DOS completely and take over, gaining lots of memory in the process. I don't recall whether you could exit from the game back to the command prompt. Some games where "play until you reboot".

Re. 5. The .EXE header does not "point" to any stack, there is no stack section you imply, the concept of sections doesn't exist as far as the .EXE file is concerned. The SS *register* value is [obtained by](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) adding the segment the executable was loaded at with the SS value from the header.

It's true that the *linker* can arrange sections contiguously in the .EXE file, but such sections' properties are not included in the .EXE header. They often can be reverse-engineered by inspecting the executable.

Re. 6. The SS and SP values in the .EXE header are not file pointers. The EXE file might have a part that maps to the stack, but that's entirely optional.

Re. 7. This is already [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13663811/1329652).

Re. 8. This looks like a debug symbol list. The cheat utility was linked with the debugging information left in. You can have completely arbitrary data there - often it'd various resources (graphics, music, etc.).