# assembly 8086 - multiply two matrix

Tags: assembly, matrix, multiplication, emu8086

This piece of code should multiply two matrix keeping the sign of the correspondive elements

```
N EQU 3
M EQU 4
P EQU 2

.MODEL small
.STACK
.DATA

matA DB  4,-3,5,1,3,-5,0,11,-5,12,4,-5
matB DB  -2,3,5,-1,4,3,9,-7
matC DW  N*P DUP(?)


.CODE
.STARTUP

XOR  AX,AX
XOR  BX,BX
XOR  CX,CX
XOR  DX,DX
XOR  SI,SI
XOR  DI,DI
XOR  BP,BP

MOV  CX,N
decN:
PUSH CX
PUSH BX     
            MOV  CX,P
            decP:
            PUSH CX
            PUSH BP

                        MOV  CX,M
                        MOV  DI,0
                        decM:
                        PUSH CX
                        XOR  AH,AH
                        MOV  AL,matA[BX][DI]
                        PUSH BX
                        MOV  BX,BP
                        MOV  DL,matB[DI][BX]
                        POP  BX
                        IMUL DL
                        MOV  SI,BP
                        ADD  matC[BX][SI],AX
                        INC  DI
                        POP  CX
                        LOOP decM
            INC  BP                   
            POP  CX

            LOOP decP
INC  BX                            
POP  CX

LOOP decN

.EXIT
END
```

It will not terminate because after the first cycle CX will be decremented when its value is 0, so it will be pushed FFFF into the stack and that will generate a mess. The second problem is that it is not able to pick the correct values from the matrix after the first cycle. Under `decM:` I had to move the BP value into BX because a wrong offset is calculated by the emulator.

Comment: One mistake I noticed: You should `POP` the register before incrementing it: So `POP BP` before you `INC  BP ` and `POP BX` before you `INC BX`. Overall, make sure that for every `PUSH` there is a `POP` (unless you'd use advanced techniques, of course).

Comment: `matB[DI][BX]` isn't 2D indexing, it's just `matB[DI + BX]`.  I don't know why emu8086 supports that confusing syntax, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

`matB[DI][BX]` isn't 2D indexing, it's just `matB[DI + BX]`.  I don't know why emu8086 supports that confusing syntax, but I wouldn't recommend it.

8086 machine code only supports simple addition in addressing modes, so you need something like `add DI, N` to stride through a column vector.

> Under `decM`: I had to move the BP value into BX because a wrong offset is calculated by the emulator.

That's odd.  At first I wondered if you had the right offset but the wrong segment base (because BP implies SS while BX implies DS), but [`.model small` gives you DS=SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Memory_models).

**But I think you need to initialize DS yourself.  If I understand correctly, a DOS `.exe` starts with DS base = start of the PSP.  [Why doesn't MS-DOS initialize the DS and ES registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663811/why-doesnt-ms-dos-initialize-the-ds-and-es-registers).**

So you probably have the right offset, but the wrong segment base, resulting in the wrong linear address.  If `BP` works, then it's not the offset that's wrong in the `seg:off` addressing mode.

Once you fix this, you should be able to debug your code using the debugger.  Segments can be confusing, but the rest should be easy to debug by single-stepping, and looking up any surprising instruction in the manual.

`[BP+BX]` isn't a valid addressing mode, so yes you do need `MOV  SI,BP` before `ADD  matC[BX][SI],AX`.  Or `add bx,bp` or something if you can clobber a register.

**You might just increment 3 pointers (destination, column-source, and row-source)** with `inc` or `add reg,N` / `sub reg,P-1` or whatever, instead of trying to keep `i`, `j`, and `k` indices in registers and scaling them before every 2D access.

---

**Unbalanced push/pop**

Your inner loop has 2 push and 2 pop.  But your outer 2 loops (`decN` and `decP`) each have 2 push and 1 pop.  This appears doomed to failure, and would overflow the stack with larger N.

I haven't tried to figure out exactly which value is supposed to go where, and if you're *trying* to always pop a value back into the register it came from or if you're using the save/restore as an opportunity to pop it into a different register.  There are no comments in your code...

---

Using all the registers instead of memory is good, but you *are* needing to use some memory.  You might have an easier time (and more efficient code) if you use BP as a frame pointer, so you have random access to the stack.  Restricting yourself to push/pop for saving/restoring means you have to save/restore in the inner loop instead of just keeping some outer-loop thing in memory.

You could keep a loop counter in memory, like `dec byte [BP-2]` / `jnz decP` instead of saving/restoring CX to use it as the loop counter for all 3 loops.

Or with pointers in registers, you could check them instead of spending a separate register or memory location as a loop counter.  Like

```
top_of_loop:
      ...
    ; bottom of a loop
    cmp DI, OFFSET matC + N*P * 2
    jb  top_of_loop
      ; fall through when DI has 

 ; or OFFSET matC + SIZEOF matC, or put a label at the end of matC
```

Then you have CX available as a temporary (like accumulating a row/column dot product that will become an element of the result matrix, with `add cx, ax`), or for holding a loop bound if you want to support runtime-variable matrix sizes.

You also don't need to use DX the way you are.  `imul byte ptr matB[DI][BX]` will work without needing a separate load into a register.  (Or `imul  byte ptr [BX]` with a pointer.)  That leaves you DX free.

Comment: can you tell me why `matA[BX][DI]` is picking the correct value while `matB[BX][DI]` is not? In the first place I tried to store the values of my B matrix in a different order but it always pick the wrong one

Comment: @TonyRomero: I don't know, I haven't tried to follow your program logic in enough detail.  There are no comments, and you haven't shown what you actually get vs. what you expect.